# tbb::parallel_for variable scope

Tags: c++, tbb

Im attempting my first tbb::parallel_for loop and I need some help. I seem to get through the loop fine but im not sure how to set the variable "test" in a global scope. Outputting during the loop I can see the values are correct but once I exit the loop and output "test" again the values is 0. Please help

```
int test =0;
tbb::parallel_for(
tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<MeshData>::iterator>(meshData.begin(),
meshData.end()),
[&] (tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<MeshData>::iterator> meshData) {
for (std::vector<MeshData>::iterator it = meshData.begin(); it != meshData.end(); it++) {

    test = (*it).posX;
    cout << test << endl; // has correct value
}
});
cout << test << endl; // has incorrect value value
```

Comment: Did you try to give `test` by capture to your lambda, try adding `&test`in the brackets

Comment: Yes I tried that but still no luck, what am I missing here:(

Comment: it's called data-race. Your program is ill-defined according to C++ standard since you cannot communicate across threads using variable of a regular type. Writing to a shared variable  requires synchronization and just is inefficient after all. Look at `tbb::parallel_reduce` if you need reduction into a single value.

Comment: @Anton seems like a fair conclusion, _reduce did work with my simple example